# MySQL: Create database like?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I want to clone certain databases. Is there such a thing as a

```
CREATE DATABASE LIKE <template database here>
```

command?
I know, there is

```
CREATE TABLE LIKE
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to clone a database, `my_database` for example, you'll want to run a mysql query and then run a command in the linux terminal:

mysql> `CREATE DATABASE my_database_copy;`

linux terminal (on the machine with the database):
`mysqldump -u username -p my_database | mysql -u username -p my_database_copy`

From there you'll likely get 2 "Enter password:" prompts....just input your password, press enter, and wait :)

Comment: You'll want to make sure you grant privileges on ````my_database_copy```` before you pipe output from ````my_database````

Answer (score 2):

There is no such command.

But you can create a [backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) (SQL file) of your database, and then [restore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) all objects in the new database.

Also, you can use GUI tools in dbForge Studio for MySQL (free express edition) - [Backup or restore a database](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-administration.html). It will help you quickly recreate database and its contents.

Answer (score 1):

1. I will prefer taking backup and restoring
2. If it's just for cloning, I will go for `MySQLDump`

---

**This is just one another way of doing:**

```
mysql> create database new_dbname;

mysql> select concat('create table
new_dbname.',TABLE_NAME,' like wings2020.',TABLE_NAME,'; insert into
new_dbname.',TABLE_NAME,' select * from ol_dbname.',TABLE_NAME,';')
from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'old_dbname'  into
outfile '/tmp/a.txt'; 

mysql> source /tmp/a.txt;
```